# How to concat two DataFrames by comparing overlapping columns in pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

`df1` and `df2` are the two `DataFrame` objects from measurement with their own relative time stamps (no absolute time). The last `n` values of `df1['voltage']` are the first `n` of `df2['voltage']`, i. e. there is overlapping data. `n` is unknown to me.

I now want `df3`, which concatenates `df1` and `df2` in such a way that the redundant data is left out.

Is there a way to do this using pandas? I've tried looking into the `merge`
, `join` and `concat` methods, but I didn't find any solutions to my question -- the lack of an absolute time in order to compare the two objects seems to be the problem. A short example (in general, time and voltage are floats, not ints):

df1

```
      name          value          dim         time          voltage
       abc            000            s            0                5
       ghi            001            m            1                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            2                5
       NaN            NaN          NaN            3                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            4                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            5                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            6                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            7                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            8                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            9                6
```

df2

```
      name          value          dim         time          voltage
       abc            000            s            0                7
       ghi            001            m            1                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            2                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            3                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            4                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            5                4
       NaN            NaN          NaN            6                2
       NaN            NaN          NaN            7                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            8                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            9                7
```

In this example, the last 5 values of `df1` are present in `df2`. The operation should deliver

df3

```
      name          value          dim         time          voltage
       abc            000            s            0                5
       def            001            m            1                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            2                5
       NaN            NaN          NaN            3                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            4                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            5                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            6                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN            7                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            8                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN            9                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN           10                4
       NaN            NaN          NaN           11                2
       NaN            NaN          NaN           12                6
       NaN            NaN          NaN           13                7
       NaN            NaN          NaN           14                7
```

It *feels* like a simple and common problem, but I cannot find anything and my only idea right now is something along the lines of

```
for i in xrange(1, len(df1['voltage'])):
    l1 = df1['voltage'][-i:].values
    l2 = df2['voltage'][:i].values
    if np.allclose(l1, l2):
        n = i
```

and then using `concat`. This is excruciatingly slow (especially since I cannot `break` after one match is found; there could be others later).

Is there a fast (and preferably easy) way to do this in pandas?

Comment: This is fraught with danger, you have no method to uniquely determine which values overlap as your time values clash in both df's, you could try to determine if a range of values match and then concat the remaining values **if** you were sure that this is correct but you have a small range in df1 that overlaps with df2 and really there isn't a sane method I can think that would not overwrite or lose values in the merge

Comment: @EdChum That's what I was afraid of. Unfortunately, there is no way for me to get a unique time stamp out of my files (or even save them with one after measurement).

Comment: To the extent I understand the question, I think your approach is sound, though I don't understand why you can't exit the loop after finding a match.  I think there is probably room to optimize that for loop.  In particular, do it all in numpy and make sure to create `l1` and `l2` just once and then do comparisons of views to them (rather than all the repeated copying that you do now).  I just added a numpy tag to the question, btw.

Comment: @JohnE with `l1 = [1, 4, 5, 4, 5]; l2 = [4, 5, 4, 5, 6]` my approach yields n = 2 and n = 4 with 4 being the desired result. Thanks for the hint when to create `l1` and `l2`; that makes a lot of sense and the code faster.

Comment: I see.  In that case, why not go from n to 1 instead of 1 to n?  Then you could exit after the first match, right?